# PHP cache to disk using fwrite

Tags: php, caching, fwrite, fclose

I'm using the following codes to cache URLs visited, hopefully saving some CPU. At the beginning of the php files:

```
$url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$break = Explode('/', $url);
$file = $break[count($break) - 1];
$cachefile = 'cache/cached-'.$file.'.html';
$cachetime = 900;

// Serve from the cache if it is younger than $cachetime
if (file_exists($cachefile) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)) {
  //  echo "<!-- Cached copy, generated ".date('H:i', filemtime($cachefile))." -->\n";
    readfile($cachefile);
    exit;
}
ob_start();
```

At the end of the php files:

```
// Cache the contents to a cache file
$cached = fopen($cachefile, 'w');
fwrite($cached, ob_get_contents());
fclose($cached);
ob_end_flush(); // Send the output to the browser
```

This works fine, but it creates files using the full URI (ie including queries, # etc). I am trying to have the cached file written once, without anything else.

In other words, when someone visits mysite.com/index.php, I want one file index.php.html created. The if someone else visits mysite.com/index.php?sdgd=3534&#whatever&other&stuff I want the cached file to still be index.php.html therefore overwriting the previous index.php.html created. I **do not want** a cached file named index.php?sdgd=3534&#whatever&other&stuff.html - which seems to happen now.

I know it probably has to do with:

```
$cachefile = 'cache/cached-'.$file.'.html';
```

but couldn't figure it out myself.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: What if the page is generated using values from the parameters.  This would surely need to know this data, sometimes even cookies can be relevant.

Comment: _Side note:_ You don't need to worry about the hashes `#`. Those aren't passed to PHP  (they are for the client).

Comment: If requests for both `https://example.com/index.php?sdgd=3534` and `https://example.com/index.php?sdgd=9876` are to be cached as `index.php.html` (i.e., in the same file), does it mean that `sdgd` doesn't have any effect in the server response?

Comment: So `$file` appears to contain `?` sometimes? Maybe a string contains checks?

Comment: Why don't you create a hash for the filename? Then there's no need to take care of escaping.

Comment: You should also use the full path as the cache key, otherwise you'll have cache collisions like `foo/index.php` and `bar/index.php` both using `index.php` as the cache key.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions guys. That wasn't the case, so I'm gonna asnwer my own question. Apparently the answer was as easy as changing

```
$url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

into

```
$url = strtok($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '?');
```

This seems to cache a file with a name excluding the queries.

Comment: By the way, I've ended up not using it after all, because I'm using NginX + php-fpm, and this (as far as I know) already does the caching of processed php files.

Comment: I'm sure that Nginx and php-fpm behave as expected, that is to say, script requests execute the script and return the output. Anything else wouldn't be much useful. I suspect your hosting provider has some caching layer like Varnish or perhaps you're sending HTTP headers requesting browsers to heavily cache requests.